# Why does make do nothing?

Tags: makefile

I'm using [GNU Make for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/make.htm) to try and make [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Overlay_Extensions/XUL_School/Setting_Up_a_Development_Environment) firefox extension. I cd to the directory with the makefile and `make` but it just sits there. If I type `make clean` it does the same thing.

imgur is down. [Here](https://veuwer.com/i/3gs4.png) is a picture.

Comment: Did you follow this part of the guide?

"In most cases you'll only need to change the first lines in Makefile. These define the extension name, the extension id (as specified in install.rdf) and the name of the profile directory where the extension will be installed during development and testing. More about this further ahead."

Comment: I think it's already ready already https://veuwer.com/i/3gs5.png

Comment: You may try `make --trace` or `make -d` it should tell you what `make` actually think it should / should not build. You may also paste us the output.